# What is LEVERAGE SHARES PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY LEVERAGE SHARES 2X FACEBOOK ETP (FB2)

Tags: financial-literacy, shares, leverage

I was looking into buying FB shares and discovered something called 'LEVERAGE SHARES PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY LEVERAGE SHARES 2X FACEBOOK ETP (FB2)' . What is this and how does it relate to the usual FB symbol?

https://www.sharesmagazine.co.uk/shares/share/FB2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be an ETF that owns FB stock using 2X leverage (borrowing 50% of the capital to buy the shares).  So you should expect to get twice the return (and loss) of "regular" facebook shares.

From https://leverageshares.com/etps/fb2/:

> The Leverage Shares 2x Facebook ETP is designed to provide 2x leveraged exposure to Facebook, Inc (FB), rebalancing on a daily basis.
>
> Leverage Shares ETPs are only intended for experienced traders who understand the associated risks and are able to monitor their positions on an intraday basis. Please consult an investment adviser to determine whether or not the products are suitable for you. Traders should also review the Base Prospectus and the Leverage Shares educational materials carefully before considering the ETPs.

Comment: I'd only add "These securities are only registered for sale in the UK." No issue, per se, only this is why I'd never heard of them.

Answer (score 1):

Leverage Shares are asset backed securities (meaning the underlying is directly purchased by the ETP company) that are traded on the LSE and CBOE. Their purpose is to provide leveraged (in this case 2x) daily returns vs. those of the underlying.

On a given day, if the underlying were to rise by 2%, the leverage shares ETP would increase 4% (and vice versa, excluding fees).